# Adding AppleScript to Bash Script

Tags: bash, applescript

I have the following Bash Script.

```
!#/bin/bash 

fscanx --pdf /scandata/Trust_Report

if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
```

I would like to run the following AppleScript

```
tell application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
    activate
    show window "Trust Reports"
    do script "Scan Trust Report"
end tell



else


   say “It did not scan”



fi
```

What is the proper syntax to invoke this AppleScript?

Thank you

Comment: There are tons of links if you search for "run applescript from bash". Here is [one of many](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103621/run-applescript-from-bash-script).

Comment: [This was answered on askdifferent.stackexchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103621/run-applescript-from-bash-script)

Answer (score 8):

Use the `osascript` command. You can either pass the script as parameters using the `-e` flag, like this (note it's not necessary to break this into multiple lines, I just do that to make it more readable):

```
osascript \
    -e 'tell application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"' \
        -e 'activate' \
        -e 'show window "Trust Reports"' \
        -e 'do script "Scan Trust Report"' \
    -e 'end tell'
```

Or pass it as a here document, like this:

```
osascript <<'EOF'
tell application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
    activate
    show window "Trust Reports"
    do script "Scan Trust Report"
end tell
EOF
```

BTW, you don't need to test $? in a separate command, you can include the command you're trying to check the success of directly in the `if` statement:

```
if fscanx --pdf /scandata/Trust_Report; then
    osascript ...
else
    say “It did not scan”
fi
```

Comment: 55:61: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found class name. (-2741)